# How to create a pandas dataframe (in the form of a network edge list) using row pairwise operations on an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new pandas dataframe by applying a function over all pairwise row combinations of an existing data frame. Consider-

df:

```
          Col1  Col2  Col3 ..  Col5000
London     1     2     1         3
Paris      2     3     1         2
New York   9     1     2         2
..
Row200     1     2     9         3
```

I want to be able to apply a function func(RowX, RowY) and achieve the following dataframe:

```
Source    Target    Weight
London    Paris     func(London,Paris)
London    New York  func(London,New York)
..
```

What is the fastest/most efficient way to do this? Do I need to use itertools.combinations() for the rows?

**EDIT**

Here is what func does:

```
def func(RowX,RowY):
  '''
  The possible values that Col 3 can take are: [1,2,3,9]
  Now, I call it an agreement when the values at the same index of 
  RowX and RowY are either both 1 or both 2.
  It is a disagreement when when one is 1 and the other is 0.
  For all calculations, wherever a 9 occurs, the index in question is 
  discarded, regardless of whether 9 occurs in only one of the rows or both 
  rows.
  All other cases (those involving various combinations consisting of the 
  value 3 are called All_Other_Cases.
  '''

  numerator=Sum_Of_Agreements-Sum_Of_Disagreements
  denominator=Sum_of_Agreements+Sum_Of_Disagreements+All_Other_Cases

  return numerator/denominator
```

Comment: It depends on what `func` is.

Comment: @piRSquared Sure, I've edited my question to reflect the situation better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I immensely appreciate your help @piRSquared! And yes, I had been upvoting responses but they wouldn't show because I had been below the limit.

Comment: Hi @piRSquared I was wondering if you could still look into this question. Thanks in advance.